# Filter out records based on condition SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to filter out some records based on condition but couldn't get the proper results.

Data:

```
GID OID SID  Z
1   1   1    A
1   2   2    B
1   3   3    C
1   2   4    B
```

Expected Result:

```
GID OID SID Z
1   1   1   A
1   3   3   C
```

Here GID, OID can be repeated but not SID.

Need to filter out all records where Z contains 'A' & 'C'

What I have tried:

```
select distinct GID, OID, SID, Z
from table
where Z ilike ('A') or Z ilike ('C')
```

but this query will include all record of sample GID records.
Moreover I have also thought of self join but could not frame the query around that.

Comment: Did you mean `OID` can't be repeated?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: Surely you are "filtering out" where Z is *not* A or C, ie, rows where Z is duplicated?

Comment: @DanielA.White Efforts mentioned.

Comment: @ITgoldman I have already said that `OID` can be repeated

Comment: "*Here GID, OID can be repeated but not SID.*" - SID values are never repeated in your SID field.

Comment: @lemon not for any GID, though can be repeated in table but i was talking wrt to the sample i provided

Comment: SID values are not repeated in general: row1 SID = 1, row2 SID = 2, row3 SID = 3, row4 SID = 4. Check the values in your table and the name of your fields.

Comment: yes they are linked to one GID here...but GID value changes, there might be possibility that SID will repeat

Comment: You should update your output table according to the input table shared here, otherwise sharing these tables becomes irrelevant. If you want a solid solution, your input table should exhibit all borderline cases, including your repeated SID values.

Comment: Mysql doesn't have `ilike`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the query you need

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        gid, oid, sid, z,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn
    FROM data
    WHERE LOWER(z) LIKE '%a%'
          OR LOWER(Z) LIKE '%c%'
)
SELECT gid, oid, sid, z FROM cte c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT sid FROM cte t 
    WHERE t.z = c.z
          AND t.sid = c.sid 
          AND t.rn < c.rn
)
```

I use `ROW_NUMBER` to be able to check if a `sid` value repeats.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f3b06b1e66e7417f7260714bbd5d35b1)